# Year generation in python in from of academic year format (eg :2015-2016)

Tags: python

in python is it posssible to generate years in the format as academic year format. for eg `2015-2016`, which starts from September of `2015` to june of `2016`.

for eg:

```
2015-2016
2016-2017
2017-2018  etc.
```